# Knockout Filtered Binding

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I'm looking for some guidance on how to get the following to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/gdefilippi/qgr1s51s/4/

In the fiddle above I've got two observableArrays.  One provides a filter to the other.  This will be applied to async calls in a larger project.

Anyway I'm looping on the segments, then looping on the items filtered by segment.  Everything is good there.

When I push a new item into the items observableArray the result is not rebound.  How would I get the rebind to work correctly and easily.  In the below code and in the Fiddle looking to have the add which pushes an item into the observableArray items (see the add function) update, the issue is the binding is against the filtering function.

Samples:

```
var vm = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        {label:'item1',segment:1},
        {label:'item2',segment:2}
    ]);
    self.segments = ko.observableArray([
        {title:'Segment 1',id:1},
        {title:'Segment 2',id:2}
    ]);
    self.bysegment = function(segment){
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function (_item){
            return _item.segment === segment;
        });
    };
    self.add = function(id){
        self.items.push({
            label:'new',
            segment:id
        });
        alert(items().length)
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);

<!-- ko foreach: segments -->
<h1 data-bind="text: title + ' : ' + id"></h1>
    <!-- ko foreach: bysegment(id) -->
    <span data-bind="text: label + ' : ' + segment"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
<button type="button" data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Thanks,
Geoffrey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your by segment function is not a knockout observable variable so it cannot update the ui. You can make it a [computed variable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) and when the observable variables you use to get the computed variable is updated, the computed variable will be updated too. So that is your list.

or You can build a more structured model binding by getting the segments to a seperate model like ;

Here i changed your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgr1s51s/7/)

```
var segment = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title);

    self.items = ko.observableArray(data.items);


    self.newItem = function (data) {
        self.items.push({
            label: 'new',
            segment: data.id()
        });
        alert(self.items().length);
    }
}
```

and in your main vm

```
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    var dbItems = [{
        label: 'item1',
        segment: 1
    }, {
        label: 'item2',
        segment: 2
    }];

    var dbSegments = [{
        title: 'Segment 1',
        id: 1
    }, {
        title: 'Segment 2',
        id: 2
    }];

    self.segments = ko.observableArray([]);

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(dbSegments, function (item) {
        self.segments.push(new segment({
            id: item.id,
            title: item.title,
            items: ko.utils.arrayFilter(dbItems, function (_item) {
                return _item.segment === item.id;
            })
        }));
    });

};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: So I updated the fiddle and it appears to work as I wanted it to.  Funny thing was that I had to not pass a variable into the click call, but allow it to send in the obj calling. http://jsfiddle.net/gdefilippi/qgr1s51s/9/

Comment: Glad you have solved the issue. And give a chance to work with objects. It will help when the number of components in your page increases.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gdefilippi/qgr1s51s/9/

html:

```
<!-- ko foreach: segments -->
<h1 data-bind="text: title + ' : ' + id"></h1>
    <!-- ko foreach: bysegment(id) -->
    <span data-bind="text: label + ' : ' + segment"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
<button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JavaScript:

```
var vm = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        {label:'item1',segment:1},
        {label:'item2',segment:2}
      ]);
    self.segments = ko.observableArray([
        {title:'Segment 1',id:1},
        {title:'Segment 2',id:2}
    ]);

    self.bysegment = function(id){

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function (_item){
            return _item.segment === id;
        });
    };

    self.add = function(obj){

        self.items.push({
            label:'new',
            segment:obj.id
        });
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```